# Development: how to know current site selected in Control Panel

Tags: extension, multi-site-manager, development

I'm developing a custom extension that should work also in Control Panel.
In an EE MSM environment I need to know which site is selected (site_id).
Is there any variabile?

I can't find anything in EE Development Doc.

Comment: If you can, please mark my answer as being correct. It's best practice to accept the correct answer so others know. And in this case, there is no debate that the answer is correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$this->EE->config->item('site_id');
```

Or

```
config_item('site_id');
```

Comment: I've never even seen that second syntax! Do you happen to know whether it's deprecated/official/whatever?

Comment: @AdrianMacneil just browsed the source, it's defined in CodeIgniter and I think only references `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` for config items. It's also in the [CI docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/common_functions.html). [Here's how a CI Reactor Engineer uses it](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/185036/#874609). pretty cool.